# highlight a DOM element on mouse over, like inspect does

Tags: javascript, html, dom, bookmarklet, highlight

We have a bookmarklet, and the user clicks a button and an inspect like highligther needs to kick in. We want to this to be cross browser.

For this we need to detect the DOM element during the mouse move, and once we have this element we need to highlight with CSS.

We have problems detecting the DOM element by mouse move, can you guide us how this is done?

Once we have this DOM element, on user click we need to extract XPath.

Comment: Have you attempted anything yet? Have you any code?

Comment: We have found how to extract the XPath of a tag, see my other questions.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can hook `mousemove` on `document` or `document.body`, then use the `target` property of the event object to find out the topmost element the mouse is over. Then applying CSS to it is probably most easily done by adding a class to it.

It's tempting to think the [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) psuedo-class could do it without JavaScript, but I'm struggling to see how to apply it only to the "deepest" hovered element (for instance, in `<p>x<em>y</em>z</p>`, only to the `em` and not the `p`).

Here's an example using JavaScript (not `:hover`):

```js
let prev = null;

document.body.addEventListener(
    "mouseover",
    (event) => {
        if (event.target === document.body || (prev && prev === event.target)) {
            return;
        }
        if (prev) {
            prev.classList.remove("highlight");
            prev = null;
        }
        if (event.target) {
            prev = event.target;
            prev.classList.add("highlight");
        }
    },
    false
);
```

```css
.highlight {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p>I'm a paragraph, with <strong>some strong text</strong>, and some <em>emphasized text</em>.</p>
<p>I'm another paragraph.</p>
<div>Here's a div</div>
```

Comment: This :hover class does work for any HTML dom element? And does work in every browser? Do you know if it's supported by older version like FF 3.5 and IE7?

Comment: @IonutFlaviusPogacian: `:hover` does indeed work with any element in IE7 or higher (not in IE6, which only supported it on anchors). But I'd have to think carefully about how to structure the CSS. Just `body *:hover { ... }` probably wouldn't do it, if you want to highlight only the *topmost* element the mouse is over...

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle that could show something similar http://jsfiddle.net/MBujm/ Ignore the jQuery, it's not needed.

Comment: @Esailija and T.J.Crowder you please check out this related question [Mouseover event doesn't granulate on IE9 for sub elements, event doesn't start on IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052988/mouseover-event-doesnt-granulate-on-ie9-for-sub-elements-event-doesnt-start-o)

Comment: It's really helpful but i need iframe inside does not work..Kindly please anyone help.

Answer (score 6):

With the help of jquery you can do something like this

```
$('*').hover(
    function(e){
        $(this).css('border', '1px solid black');
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    },function(e){
        $(this).css('border', 'none');
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
);
```

With this code in your bookmarklet, you can load what ever code

```
javascript:function loadScript(src){f=document.createElement('script');if(f){f.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");f.setAttribute("src",src);document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(f);}};loadScript("yourscripturl");
```

Comment: Do you happen to know how this is done with plain javascript? It's a bit problematic to load JQuery in a bookmarklet.

Comment: I just edit my answer, you can use a bookmarklet code to load a biget code which can contain jquery and do whatever you want

Comment: change `yourscripturl` at the end

Comment: Wow! This is awesome as you can now do so much more with bookmarklets!  However, I would also suspect that it's also kinda dangerous as it would open more security holes, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Adrian unless you intentionally load bad script yourself or someone hijack your url and add their bad script there then yes it a security bug

Comment: @James : Small addition . Better you keep if any existing border to a variable and set it instead of setting the border to 'none'. Otherwise it will keep removing existing borders of elements :-)