# Mouseover event doesn't granulate on IE9 for sub elements, event doesn't start on IE8

Tags: javascript, html, dom, highlight

We were adapting a method posted here [highlight a DOM element on mouse over, like inspect does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010569/highlight-a-dom-element-on-mouse-over-like-inspect-does/11010645#11010645) to **NOT use jQuery**.

We came up with this solution so far: http://jsfiddle.net/pentium10/Q7ZQV/3/

This seams to work on Chrome and Firefox, but doesn't work as expected on IE.

1. On IE9 for example the highlight doesn't occur on minor elements like the tag line eg: `javascript, html, dom` or the top line like: `chat, meta, faq`

   When I mouse over the javascript tag the big div is highligthed and this is [wrong](http://screencast.com/t/NZ9W4xre) and it should be [like we see in Firefox](http://screencast.com/t/MwttbVKrXr)
2. On IE8 and 7 it doesn't start, so that is another problem we need to fix

Comment: See: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Comment: In IE9, the highlight does occur on the JavaScript tag. Start at the left side, and move to the right, in the direction of the tags. Then, the tags are highlighted. It seems that the overlay is prevents the "hover event" from being propagated in IE9 and 10.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turns out that in IE, elements that have no background (i.e. `background: transparent`) and the [Gradient filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532997%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) set do not receive mouse events. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jefferyto/pHjFr/)

This is a happy coincidence, since you're using a [RGBa background colour](http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/) for your overlay and one of the workarounds for RGBa colours in IE is the Gradient filter.

By setting these styles on the overlay (for IE):

```
background: transparent;
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#7F000000,endColorstr=#7F000000)"; /* IE8 */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#7F000000,endColorstr=#7F000000);   /* IE6 & 7 */
zoom: 1;
```

mouse events pass through the overlay and onto the underlying elements, so inner / minor elements are highlighted correctly.

Other issues that are present in IE7/8:

- When using [`element.attachEvent`](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html#link6), the event name needs to be prefixed with "on":

  ```
  document.body.attachEvent('onmouseover', function(e) { ... })
  ```
- To find the [target of the event](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#target), you need to access `event.srcElement` instead of `event.target`.
- As rodneyrehm mentioned, `Array.indexOf` isn't supported.

So here's a version of your solution that also works in IE 7-9: http://jsfiddle.net/jefferyto/Q7ZQV/7/

(BTW The highlighting is wrong for inline elements that span more than one line, e.g. the "ask your own question" link in the "Browse other questions..." line.)

Answer (score 12):

I think I found the problem in your implementation. But before we get to that, you might want to cure yourself of the global-scope-leak you present in line 45. There is a semicolon, where you probably want a comma:

```
var target = e.target,
    offset = findPos(target),
    width = target.offsetWidth;//target.outerWidth(),
    height = target.offsetHeight;//target.outerHeight();
```

You might also be interested in knowing [Array#indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) is supported since IE9 so `~no.indexOf(e.target)` would fail in IE8 and below.

Now to your problem. Current Browsers (including Firefox) know `pointer-events:none`. Even IE10's support is [still unknown](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events). Any browser not supporting pointer-events will *never* fire the `mouseenter` event on elements that are covered by your overlay.

With IE7+ supporting [document.elementFromPoint()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.elementFromPoint) you could bind to `mousemove`, hide the layer, detect the element below the cursor, fire the `mouseover` if necessary. If you go down this road, please consider throttling your `mousemove` events (see [limit.js](https://github.com/m-gagne/limit.js/blob/master/limit.js)).

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rodneyrehm/KzeSd/).

**Update:**

I haven't done any performance comparison of `document.elementFromPoint()` vs `pointer-events:none`. Current browsers (Firefox, Chrome, …) can deal with both, Internet Explorer can only work with the `document.elementFromPoint()` approach. To keep things simple I did not implement the alternate `pointer-events:none` route for modern browsers.

Comment: It turns out the client wants this to work on mobile/tablets also. Just for opinion, is there a way we could track somehow the finger move on tablets?

Comment: Your client is aware of the fact that with touch screen devices *you cannot hover over things*, right? So you'll have to hook into a "tap" (I'd still call it a click, but, well…). Look into [pointer.js](https://github.com/borismus/pointer.js) for a library that even helps with gestures

Comment: a quick thought on performance: `document.elementFromPoint()` is (a lot) slower then using `pointer-events:none;`. In addition to this, there are some cross browser issues, pointed out [here](http://help.dottoro.com/ljctoqhf.php), guess which browser is being obtuse?

Comment: I've tested http://jsfiddle.net/jefferyto/Q7ZQV/7/show/ with IE9, Firefox and Safari in various zoom levels. The elementFromPoint() approach works fine

Answer (score 2):

Using a special routine for Internet Explorer (tested in IE9, not tested in IE8), I have come up with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Vw3yX/5/). However, it is not perfect, yet. When moving the mouse inside the same element, flickering occurs as the routine is run multiple times (and sometimes the overlay disappears completely). I hope to perfect this soon.

Routine:

- I specifically checked if the browser was IE and performed the following actions:
- I assigned the `mousemove` event to a function that uses `document.elementFromPoint(x, y)`.
- I assigned `mouseover` to a clearing function, that removes the overlay immediately. (This causes the flickering and a possible complete overlay removal, even though the mouse is still on the element.)

Element From Point Function

```
function ep(e)
{
    var ev = {target:document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY)};
    handler(ev);
}
```

Clearing Function

```
function clear(e)
{
   cur = null;
   overlay.style.display='none';
}
```

Feedback and suggestions are welcome. I am still working on this, and I will post updated JSFiddle links.

Comment: You can use spoon.net to test in different browsers. IE8 gives this: http://screencast.com/t/RFWr9VrT `Message: 'clientX' is null or not an object Line: 59 Char: 5`

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533567(v=vs.85).aspx, it is supported in IE4 and above.

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid the mouse events being intercepted by the overlay by changing its properties, namely by making it transparent and relying on `outline` or, with size calculation adjustments, `border`:

```
background:transparent;
outline:1px dotted red;
```

[Fiddle'd](http://jsfiddle.net/Q7ZQV/6/)

Alternatively, you could *not* rely on an overlay but instead toggle a class on the element itself whenever "moused over". If you cache the reference to it, you could then remove the class when "moused out", rinse, repeat. I'll fiddle with the idea for a little bit more to see how viable it is.

Comment: If you altered the background of an element, wouldn't any `background:inherit` of contained elements adjust accordingly? this could look confusing…

Comment: @rodneyrehm: initial value for color is `transparent` - and there are few scenarios where `inherit` would be a preferable choice.

Comment: I'm aware of that, I'm just pointing out that there *are* situations where this approach might break. I like the `background:transparent` idea on the overlay, though. I'm not sure if performs better than `display:none`. Currently no idea how to benchmark that reliably :/

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick look at your fiddle, and forked a version that works on IE8, [to be found here](http://jsfiddle.net/e9TN3/1/). As it turns out, `indexOf`, especially in combination with the bitwise `~` is something IE doesn't seem to be all that fond of, so the quickest fix seems to be a simple `for(i=0;i<no.length;i++){}`.

As pointed out before, `e.target` won't work in IE, as JScript calls this property `srcElement`. This makes sense, since IE events always bubble up to the document, so all events have a source, rather then a target.

The biggest difference is to be found in your CSS: again IE is a pain: MS believes that `rgba` is no good for some reason. It seems they prefer writing CSS's that no human on earth can make sense of:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0.3,startColorstr='#4c333333', endColorstr='#4c666666');
```

gives you a semi-transparent grey overlay. To be honest, I found this piece of my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975688/css-background-opacity-with-rgba-not-working-in-ie-8).

When it comes to the pointer events, the only way round this, AFAIK, is another event listener, that handles the `onclick` event:

```
function noClick(e)
{
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.preventDefault)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
    e.returnValue = false;
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    return false;
}
```

Hope this helps you on your way...